# weights should have the same shape as x

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I'm trying to do pyplot hist, but it returns "weights should have the same shape as x" while I don't have any NaN and both x and weights have the same shape.

```py
for platform in platform_sales_by_year['platform'].unique():
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
    ax_1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    x=platform_sales_by_year.loc[platform_sales_by_year['platform'] == platform]
    ax_1.hist(x=x['year_of_release'], weights=x['year_sales'])
    ax_1.title.set_text(platform)
    ax_1.set_xlabel('Год')
    ax_1.set_ylabel('Количество выпущенных игр')
    plt.show()
```

[DF head and info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gkksm.png)

Also, this code returns equal values:

```
for platform in platform_sales_by_year['platform'].unique():
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
    ax_1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    x=platform_sales_by_year.loc[platform_sales_by_year['platform'] == platform]
    print(len(x['year_of_release']), len(x['year_sales']))
```

Comment: First check that you are using the latest verions of pandas (1.2.3) and of matplotlib (3.4.1).  As your x is discrete, it probably makes sense to use a bar plot instead (`ax_1.bar(x['year_of_release'], x['year_sales'])`).

Comment: @JohanC bar plot works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using pandas 0.25.8 and matplotlib 3.1.0. I guess, this is the reason for error.

@JohanC recomended to use bar plot instead and it works fine. Thank you!